# How to abort jenkins build with success from shell script

Tags: jenkins

Have a freestyle jenkins job build with a shell script like this following

```
CLIENT_CHANGED=# some logic for setting this

if [[ $CLIENT_CHANGED == false ]]
then
    # abort build if no changes to client code
    exit 0
fi
```

The `exit 0` is not actually stopping the build though. If I use `exit 1` it stops but then the build is being set to failed which I don't want.

The overall goal here is to stop the build if a certain directory within git has not been modified during the most recent commit. If there's another way to achieve that I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the exit code of a script to a variable by using the `returnStatus` option. Then later in the script you can exit with a chosen build status via the `error()` function. Unfortunately, you can't exit prematurely with `SUCCESS` (it will just result in failure status) but you can still use `ABORTED`.

Here's a sample pipeline script that hopefully demonstrates how this could work:

```
stages {
    stage("Run script") {
        steps {
            script {
                exitCode = sh(script: "exit 1", returnStatus: true)
            }
        }
    }

    stage("Abort the build") {
        when {
            expression {
                !exitCode
            }
        }

        steps {
            script {
                currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"

                error("No changes to client code")
            }
        }
    }

    stage("Fail the build") {
        when {
            expression {
                exitCode
            }
        }

        steps {
            script {
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

                error("Build failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See:

1. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/
2. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/885/cleanest-way-to-prematurely-exit-a-jenkins-pipeline-job-as-a-success/12776#12776

======================

For freestyle builds, you can achieve very similar functionality by making use of the "Exit code to set build unstable" option that comes with the shell script build step. Just make sure to choose an exit code other than 0.

[image: Jenkins freestyle job]

The above steps will give the following output when `$CLIENT_CHANGED == false`:

```
Building step 1
Setting the build status to unstable, but continuing the build
Building step 2
```

and when `$CLIENT_CHANGED == true`:

```
Building step 1
Building as usual
Building step 2
```

Comment: I'm using a freestyle jenkins job, not a pipeline. Sorry for not mentioning that, I updated the post.

Comment: @d512 Updated the answer to give a solution for freestyle builds.

Comment: The problem with that is that it doesn't actually stop the job. As you can see, it continues on to `Building step 2`.